# Find the number of cosets of $S_{n-1}$ in $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, quotient-group

> Find the number of cosets of $S_{n-1}$ in $S_n$.

My attempt:

The number of elements in $S_{n-1}$ is $(n-1)!$ and in $S_n$ is $n!$ , so the number of cosets should be $n$ [by Lagrange's theorem]. How do I proceed from here ? How do I prove that the $n$ cosets will be distinct?

Comment: The number of cosets is the index of $S_{n-1}$ in $S_n$ which is, in turn, $\frac{|S_n|}{|S_{n-1}|} = \frac{n!}{(n-1)!} = n$.

Comment: In what sense $S_{n-1}\le S_n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To represent the cosets explicitly:

To start: $S_n$ acts on $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ and let $H$ be the subgroup isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$ that fixes $n$ i.e., $H = \{\pi \in S_n: \pi(n)=n\}$.

Then the $k$-th coset of $H$; $k=1,\ldots, n-1$ are the set of elements $\pi$ that satisfy $\pi(n) = k$.

What GSofer said about Lagrange's Thm.

Comment: So we identify $S_{n-1}$ with its image via the embedding into $S_n$ by the extension $\pi(n)=n$, is it?

Comment: Sure. But for any element $k$ the subgroup of $S_n$ that fixes $k$ is isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically done, since by Lagrange's theorem - they are distinct.

Comment: So is there a way in which I can find out the $n$ cosets?